# What is my private key?

Tags: private-key

No computer at the moment, so I have Wallets at two independent websites.  I sent millibits from one wallet to the other.  I hear that you have to use your private key to do that.  So, I guess that site created the private key for me, and they control it?  I certainly don’t know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you use an online wallet service, you are trusting the website operator to generate and maintain your private key(s) for your account.

There is a saying that goes something like, "Unless you hold your own private keys, your bitcoins aren't really yours."